# commandButton doesn't set correctly f:param if it got a javascript method in onclick event

Tags: jsf-2, xhtml, onclick, html-rendering

Between two JSF views xhtmls (both have view scoped backing beans) I would like to pass parameters if the user click a link or a button. If I have an attribute onclick with a JavaScript function to open another page (in this page I would like to use the parameters set in the first page) to the commandButton or commandLink I get the `f:param` attributes to be `\'currentAccess\':\'3\',\'gridNo\':\'5\',` and if I don't have an onclick attribute I have it right `'currentAccess':'3','gridNo':'5',`
If I have:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{statisticsBean.showAccessIncorectAnswers()}" target="_blank"
    value="#{strings.whatHaveDoDoneWrong}" rendered="#{o.date != '-' and o.answerNoWrong != 0}">
    <f:param name="currentAccess" value="#{o.currentAccess}"/>      
    <f:param name="gridNo" value="#{o.noGrid}"/>
    <f:param name="gridCategory" value="#{o.category}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

the HTML rendering looks like:

```
<input type="submit" name="j_idt73:0:j_idt74:j_idt77" value="Ce ai gresit" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('j_idt73:0:j_idt74'),{'j_idt73:0:j_idt74:j_idt77':'j_idt73:0:j_idt74:j_idt77','currentAccess':'1','gridNo':'5','gridCategory':'Drept Procesual Civil'},'');return false" />
```

which is good, I have access to the parameters (f:viewpara or FacesContext , I use the last one like`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("currentAccess")`)

**BUT**
If I have:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{statisticsBean.showAccessIncorectAnswers()}" target="_blank"
    onclick="confirmGridStatistics('#{strings.doYouWantToSeeTheWrongAnswersInAccessNo} #{o.currentAccess} #{strings.fromDate} #{o.date}?');"
    value="#{strings.whatHaveDoDoneWrong}" rendered="#{o.date != '-' and o.answerNoWrong != 0}">
        <f:param name="currentAccess" value="#{o.currentAccess}"/>
        <f:param name="gridNo" value="#{o.noGrid}"/>
        <f:param name="gridCategory" value="#{o.category}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

WITH a JavaScript function in onclick event I get the rendering:

```
<input type="submit" name="j_idt73:2:j_idt74:j_idt77" value="Ce ai gresit" onclick="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'confirmGridStatistics(\'Vrei sa vezi raspunsurile gresite in accessul 3 din data de 16-05-2013?\');','mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById(\'j_idt73:2:j_idt74\'),{\'j_idt73:2:j_idt74:j_idt77\':\'j_idt73:2:j_idt74:j_idt77\',\'currentAccess\':\'3\',\'gridNo\':\'5\',\'gridCategory\':\'Drept Procesual Civil\'},\'\')');return false" />
```

and in the second views backing bean I get `null` for the parameters from the FacesContext. Why is that?

**UPDATE**
I thought that

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().put("currentAccess", access);` in the action method whould solve it. But it doesn't, it gives me a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

I don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the my issue with a hack. I still don't know why is the issue described with the parameters.

My solution (I know it`s a hack):

- the JavaScipt function among other thing opened my second view (to which I wanted to pass the parameters)
- so I have put the parameters (which I want to pass) to the JavaScipt function

  ```
  <h:commandButton action="#{statisticsBean.showAccessIncorectAnswers()}" target="_blank"
      onclick="confirmGridStatistics('#{strings.doYouWantToSeeTheWrongAnswersInAccessNo} #{o.currentAccess} #{strings.fromDate} #{o.date}?'
      , '#{o.currentAccess}', '#{o.noGrid}', '#{o.category}');"
  value="#{strings.whatHaveDoDoneWrong}" rendered="#{o.date != '-' and o.answerNoWrong != 0}"/>
  ```

and the second view request URL looks like `http://myserver:port/access.xhtml?currentAccess=34&noGrid=3&category=category`

and in the second view backing bean I access the parameters with

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
String currentAccess= request.getParameter("currentAccess");
```

**STILL**
If anybody knows why is the initial issue that I would appreciate it to share.
Thank you.